# Sitecore 7.0 updated date field

Tags: sitecore

Can I check does Sitecore do any updating of this Updated Date field even without any user intervention? This is because my user reported that they did not update that article but the Last Update Date was updated recently.

Comment: `Last Updated` field can be updated when there is an agent is running and manipulating the items. Moreover, even if no change has been done on an item and clicking on the save button will also update the field

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore does not do that itself, I think. In the Statistics Field Section you see the last update and the user. To see the complete history:

In the log file you see an AUDIT log if an item is updated.

Take the GUID or path and search in the log file:

Example

> 8616 08:29:09 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Admin): Save item:
>   master:/sitecore/content/Home, language: en, version: 1, id:
>   {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}

If a item is moved then of course search on GUID instead path.

Comment: Because in the Statistics, the Updated By user can be edited to some default value, I am not able to get the original last updated by. May I know where to find in the log file ?

Comment: Inside Sitecore 7 Below Reporting tool there is the log viewer. Else the default file location is in the log directory of the Data folder.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask 1 more question. When I use the Publish site feature in Sitecore, why is it that the Publishing->Publishing date not updated? Is left blank.

Comment: The Publishing field on a Item: Publish, Unpublish, Publishing targets, Never publish. Are fields for the Publish restriction functionality. See, click Publish on top menu, Change button on the Restrictions setting. To edit this Fields in a more explaining way.